# LaunchScreen.xib UINavigationBar & UITableView

Tags: interface-builder, statusbar, tintcolor

I'm unfamiliar with Interface Builder. I typically do everything programmatically. How do I make the launch screen look like a UINavigationController as the window's root view controller with a plain-style UITableViewController as it's root view controller?

I tried adding a UINavigationBar and a UITableView to the LaunchScreen.xib provided by one of Xcode's iOS app templates, but the status bar remains transparent and doesn't automatically match the tint of the UiNavigationBar.

In Interface Builder, how do I set the tint of the status bar to match that of that of a UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use Navigation Bar and Table View simply delete the View and drag in a Navigation Controller which comes with both and appreciates the location of the status bar. To get it to build simply delete the Table View Cell.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! :-) Here's the solution: [LaunchScreen.xib](https://github.com/acani/Chats/blob/master/Chats/LaunchScreen.xib)